# How to split a columns value to different columns T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have:

| data | Subaru,Power | Toyota,Power |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.03 | 2333 | 7777 |

I need:

| data | Car type | Power |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.03 | Subaru | 2333 |
| 01.01.03 | Toyota | 7777 |

The idea was by using T-sql via loop (The column name is equalt to %_%(%))

```sql
declare @TABLE_NAME nvarchar(100) = N'something_in_the_way_Meiram'
declare @column_name nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare db_cursor cursor for 
select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME
and COLUMN_NAME like N'%_%(%)'
open db_cursor
FETCH next from db_cursor into @column_name
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    declare @job nvarchar(100)
    select top(1) @job=value from string_split(@column_name,'_')
    if(@job like N'Добыча руды')
        begin
            set @sql = N'
                select top(1) @meh = value from string_split(N'''+@column_name+''',''_'')'
        end
        
end
```

Comment: Please post your data in tabular form.  From the looks of it, it isn't clear whether `Subaru, Power` is a column header or a value.

Comment: it is column header

Comment: are the columns in your table really called `Subaru,Power` and `Toyota,Power`  ?

Comment: Yes, the columns name Subaru,Power and Toyota,Power

Comment: NEVER use 2 digit years - not even for simple demo purposes. Y2K happened more than 20 years ago, let us not repeat those mistakes. A column named "data" is another bad sign. Perhaps consider getting help for your database design - it is a skill that must be taught and learned specifically.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a query like below

```
select 
    data,
    CarType,
    Power
from yourtable
cross apply (values
    ('Subaru', [SubaruPower]),
    ('Toyota', [ToyotaPower])
) v(CarType, Power)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this solution is in oracle

```
       SELECT * FROM yourtable
       UNPIVOT(
       "POWER"   -- unpivot_clause
       FOR CAR_TYPE --  unpivot_for_clause
       IN ( -- unpivot_in_clause
       SUBARU_POWER  AS 'SUBARU', 
       TOYOTA_POWER  AS 'TOYOTA'
)
```

) ;